# Disable Javascript in web browser should disable the server validation controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, c#-4.0

I have disabled JavaScript in my web browser ,and i have a page with a text box and a button .
I kept required field validation control on my test box.
When i run the Page ,on clicking the button i am getting Validation on my text box .
How should i disabled this validation in my Page .I tried with Page.validation(); also but no solution ...Can u suggest me how to disable this validation on testbox when javascript is disabled in my web browser

```
<asp:Table ID="tbl1" runat="server" Width="197px">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell Width="60%">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Width="300%" ID="rqname" runat="server" BackColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtName" Text="Please enter Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnone" runat="server" Text="Click" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net validation controls are designed in such a way that it validates on client as well as on server. Since you only want to validate if javascript is enabled you can use jquery instead of validation control. If you dont want to use jquery you you can override the validation method (which I dont want any body should do to turn off their validation).
The easiest bet will be jquery, but why you want to do that? users will be able to submit invalid request.